# wcstombs strange behaviour

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, unicode

For some reason wcstombs cuts of everything from 1st occurrence of russian named folder in fileName.My VS project is unicode.

here is my code:

```
bool func( const TCHAR* fileName)
{
    #ifdef _UNICODE
        char path[MAX_PATH];
        wcstombs(path, fileName, ARRAYSIZE(path));
    #else
        const char* path = strFileName;
    #endif
```

I think the problem in russian names of folder in paths, for example

> D:\Новая папка\file.dat

turns into

> D:\

but

> D:\test folder\file.dat

works fine.

maybe setlocale is solution?

also this code works but I don't know if it best solution in my case.

```
CT2CA path(fileName);
```

Comment: Please post a complete example (see http://sscce.org/ ) and give some sample input, expected output and observed output.

Comment: "wcstombs cuts" ---  how do you know that? what did you actually observe?

Comment: as I said in "D:\Новая папка\file.dat"  out "D:\" , so it cut from 1st occurence of russian words.