# What is the safe way to create a v8::String from a wchar_t with non-ASCII characters?

Tags: c++, node.js, raspberry-pi, non-ascii-characters, embedded-v8

I'm writing a Node.js frontend for a [DAB development board](http://www.monkeyboard.org/products/85-developmentboard/85-dab-dab-fm-digital-radio-development-board-pro), which will eventually run on a Raspberry Pi. I am a Java and web developer, and I'm struggling with C++ and converting between different types of strings.

The DAB board comes with a C++ SDK, with a number of handy functions. It allows me to get the number of available programs with `GetTotalProgram()`. For each program I can call `GetProgramName` to get the program's name:

```
GetProgramName(char mode, long dabIndex, char namemode, wchar_t * programName)
```

... where `mode` means `FM` or `DAB`, `namemode` means long or short name. The program´s name will be returned in `programName`.

In order to convert the `wchar_t *programName` into a `v8::String`, I found this snippet that I'm using, and understand the basics of:

```
  wchar_t buff[300];
  char cbuff[600];
  GetProgramName(0, i, 1, buff);
  wcstombs( cbuff, buff, wcslen(buff) );
  Local<String> str = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, (const char *) cbuff, v8::String::kNormalString, wcslen(buff));
```

I iterate through the available programs and build up a `v8::Array`:

```
void GetPrograms(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);

  wchar_t buff[300];
  char cbuff[600];
  int numberOfPrograms, i;

  numberOfPrograms = GetTotalProgram();
  Local<v8::Array> ARRAY = Array::New(isolate, totalprogram);

  for (i = 0; i < numberOfPrograms; i++) {
    if (GetProgramName(0, i, 1, buff)) {
      wcstombs( cbuff, buff, wcslen(buff) );
      Local<String> str = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, (const char *) cbuff, v8::String::kNormalString, wcslen(buff));
      Local<Object> obj = Object::New(isolate);
      obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "name"), str);
      ARRAY->Set(i, obj);
    }
  }
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(ARRAY);
}
```

I call the C++ method from my Node app:

```
var programs = ext.getPrograms();
for (var i = 0; i < programs.length; i++) {
  console.log(programs[i][name]);
}
```

**This mostly works, but when the program's name contains a non ASCII-character, like `Æ`, `Ø`, `Å`, the *next* elements in ARRAY has a borked name**.

Here's what the Node snippet actually outputs (`console.log`), compared to the expected output:

```
| ACTUAL    | EXPECTED   |
| --------- | ---------- |
| NRK SUPER | NRK SUPER  |
| NRK VUPER | NRK VÆR    |
| NRK P1 ER | NRK P1     |
```

It seems as though the non-ASCII character causes the next `wcstombs` to quit early, not copying the later characters.

Why does this happen? Is there a better way to create a `v8::String` from my `wchar_t`?

**Note:**
I have now been able to isolate this problem down to the `wcstombs` method when running on the Raspberry Pi. The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

char cbuff[600];
wchar_t buff[300] = L"ABCø123abc";

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) {
    wcstombs( cbuff, buff, wcslen(buff) );
    wprintf(L"wcslen of wchar_t array: %u - strlen of char array: %u\n", (char) wcslen(buff), strlen(cbuff));
}
```

when run on a Mac, outputs
`wcslen of wchar_t array: 10 - strlen of char array: 10`,
but when run on the Raspberry, outputs
`wcslen of wchar_t array: 10 - strlen of char array: 3` - that is, it counts only characters before the `ø` character

This looks similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213219/wcstombs-strange-behaviour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `wcstombs( cbuff, buff, wcslen(buff) )` call, which would stop copying characters when it encountered a non-ASCII character. The [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/wcstombs/) say *The behavior of this function depends on the LC_CTYPE category of the selected C locale.*

So setting the locale to a UTF-8 variant solved the problem:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "C.UTF-8");
```

Having done this, I can now create `v8::String`s this way:

```
wchar_t buff[300] = L"Something non-ASCII ÆØÅ here";
char cbuff[600];
wcstombs( cbuff, buff, wcslen(buff) );
Local<String> str = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, (const char *) cbuff, v8::String::kNormalString, wcslen(buff));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
WCHAR str[256];0
... // fill str array here
Local<String> v8str = String::NewFromTwoByte(isolate, (const uint16_t *) str);
```

Notice `::NewFromTwoByte` usage instead of `::NewFromUtf8` and `(const uint16_t *)` cast.

> `::NewFromTwoByte` Allocates a new string from UTF-16 data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess last parameter in wcstombs is the cause of issue. Instead of trying

```
 wcstombs( cbuff, buff, wcslen(buff) );
```

try

```
memset(cbuff, 0, sizeof(cbuff));
wcstombs( cbuff, buff, sizeof(cbuff) );
```

Comment: This causes the program name to be cut off where the non-ASCII character occurs. So where I expected `NRK VÆR`, I now get `NRK V`. The other (non-ASCII) names look good.